# access to the media with jxbrowser javafx

Tags: javascript, javafx, jxbrowser

hi sorry I'm not good at English.
I realize a project javafx jxbrowser and I'm still a novice, in short during my project I had a problem in the execution of my javascript script, it does not run. I followed the instructions on this site where they did with jquery (https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013725-working-with-jquery), but nothing works
I may say that it is a problem of access to the media because my javascript code allows access to the media of the computer from the browser object.
the code works on chrome but not on jxbrowser.

please look at my code and if possible correct it for it to work.
thank you
here is my java fx code
there is the Main file, the html code and the script javaScript (I did not put the .css file because it is too long and does not cause any problem on the code because the .html file works very well on chrome)

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    pane.getChildren().add(view);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane,500,400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
@Override
public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
    if (event.isMainFrame()) {
       event.getBrowser().executeJavaScript("$('button').hide();")        }
}}); 

InputStream urlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/html/index.html");
    String html = null;
 try (BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (urlStream))) {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     String row;
     while ((row = urlReader.readLine()) != null) {
         builder.append(row);
     }
     html = builder.toString(); 
 }  catch (IOException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }

 browser.loadHTML(html);  
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

index.html

```
    <html>
<head>
<title> boilerplate </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<style>
body{
  padding-top: 5rem;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <a class = "navbar-brand" href="#"> Demo wertc </a>
  </nav>
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Reception</h2>
        <video id="receiver-video" width="100%"height="400px"></video>
<p>
<button id="start">start the connection </button>
</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Envoi</h2>
        <video id="emitter-video" width="100%"height="400px"></video>
      </div>

    </div>
<script src= "app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
 document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click',function(e){
navigator.getUserMedia({
video: true,
audio: true

},function (stream) {

let emitterVideo = document.querySelector('#emitter-video')
emitterVideo.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
emitterVideo.play()

}, function () {

})

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You read the content of the index.html file and load it using the browser.loadHTML() method. The .css and .js files are not loaded in this case, because they are included by the relative path. You can load an HTML file from the file system using the browser.loadURL() method, e.g.:

   ```
   browser.loadURL("file:///D:/media/html/index.html");
   ```
2. JxBrowser is based on Chromium engine that does not allow accessing system media devices by JavaScript from local HTML files. In order to allow accessing system media devices from local files you need to disable web security using the following Chromium switch:

   ```
   BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--disable-web-security");
   ```

   Please note that you must call this method before creating any Browser instance.
3. You're trying to use jQuery functionality, however, jQuery is not included in your HTML file. You should include jQuery or implement your logic through pure JavaScript.

Also, I recommend that you take a look at the [Remote Debugging Port](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000013082-remote-debugging-port) functionality that allows you to use Chromium DevTools to debug the loaded web page.

Comment: Hi, my code is working now. indeed it was necessary to put
         BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches ( "- disable-web-security");
to disable  security.  thank you